# iATs in ESR version 5.21.3 for Joomla

Tags: iats, esr

iATs in ESR version 5.21.3 for Joomla
Does the latest ESR CiviCRM 5.21.3 for Joomla support the latest iATs 1.7.2 for Joomla?
Thank you!
Jamie

Answer (score 1):

The iATS extension is not CMS specific. If you’re running into issues you can post in the issue queue: https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm
and we can try help you out there.